# How can I avoid the interpreter checking the function default arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, python-import, interpreter

I have a program that can either be run as a module, or as an independent file with nothing else needed to run.

When it is imported, it should import a file called 'globalSettings.py' that contains lines like `import_location = /Users/Documents/etc` that will be in the same folder as it. When it is run as `__main__`, it won't need that.

So, at the beginning of my code, I have the following:

```
try:
    import globalSettings
except ImportError:
    print("Being run as independent program")
```

Which is fine.

When I call the main function, I pass the relevant settings straight to it if is being run independently, and it has the defaults which will be used if being run as an external module.

This is the MCVE:

```
def test_func(foo, bar=globalSettings.import_location):
    do stuff
```

and I call it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_func(20, "Users/myname/testfolder/etc")
```

And when I import it from elsewhere, like `test_func(30)`, and it will find `bar` from globalSettings. However, when I run it independently, it raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/Users/tomburrows/Dropbox/Python Programming/import_test.py", line 1, in <module>
  def test_func(foo, bar=globalSettings.import_location):
NameError: name 'globalSettings' is not defined
```

It will never need globalSettings, because I will always pass bar in as an argument when I call it as an independent program, it will only need it when I run it as an import, when I'll make sure it does have a globalSettings file alongside it.

Is there anyway to ignore the error I'm getting?

Comment: You can have more than one `if __name__ == "__main__":` in your program—so you can use it to define a function two different way. i.e. Add one around two definitions of `test_func()` that makes the default something else (or doesn't give it one at all, if that makes more sense) in the appropriate case.

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally defining a name (`globalSettings`) which is then used unconditionally in your script (specifically, the function definition) is bound to fail.

What you could do is make sure the default argument always exists, even if the exception occurs:

```
try:
    import globalSettings
    import_location = globalSettings.import_location
except ImportError:
    print("Being run as independent program")
    import_location = ''  # or whatever else
```

and then define your function to have `import_location` as the default value for `bar`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I am importing lots of things from `globalSettings`, is there a quicker way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure as to what you mean by quicker. Are you using values in `globalSettings` as the default value for many  arguments in various functions?

Comment: I meant, that for each variable in `globalSettings`, I will have to add 2 lines to my code, which isn't a massive problem, but I was wondering if there was a shorter way. I am only using the variables in one function as the defaults.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of another way... I could do the `try/except` code like I put it in my question, then have `def func(foo, bar=None)`, then inside the func, have `if bar == None:` `bar = globalSettings.bar`. The last 2 lines would have to be in another `try`. I'm not sure if that is a recommended way to do it...

Comment: That would work if, when you invoke your function, the name `globalSettins` is available. From what I've understood of your question, this isn't the case.